# Jupyter Notebook Server URL Connection Failure in Docker Container in VS Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In VS Code I have created a Docker Container running in Python with a notebook in it. To run the notebook I set the kernel as the URL with the token of my Jupyter Server. The link opens fine in my browser but I am getting an error in VS Code:

> Connection Failure. Verify the server is running and reachable. (request to http://.... failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888).

When I click the http link in the error it goes to the server but it asks for me to login with my password. I am not sure if that is what is causing it but either way I have tried modifying many settings files, I've went through many GitHub discussions and I can't figure it out.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDTtN.png)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?